# Jquery - If input value greater then Balance show alert and delete value

Tags: jquery

I want to validate if an entered input value in greater then a variable amount fetched from DB. If it's greater, then show an alert and delete entered value. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function()
{
  var balance = 5; //Fetched from DB

  $('#AmountI').change(function ()
  {
    var amountI =  parseInt($('#AmountI').val());

    if( AmountI > balance)
    {
      $('#AmountI').change(function(){
        alert('Amount exeeds Balance');
        $("#AmountI").val(""); // Delete the amount
      });
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: You're not cancelling the original event callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made small example

```js
var balance = 5; //Fetched from DB

$(document).on('keyup', '#AmountI', function () {
  var $field = $(this);
  var amountI =  parseInt($field.val());

  if( amountI > balance) {
    alert('Amount exeeds Balance');
    $field.val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="AmountI">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for an extra event.

```
if( AmountI > balance)
{
    alert('Amount exeeds Balance');
    $("#AmountI").val(""); // Delete the amount
}
```